# django request.post

Tags: django

I created a custom "like" button.  The "like" is inside a post form html element.  For my view.py after i process the form post, i only want to return http response success and not load any type of success page.  What kind of object would i return in this case?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use Javascript to fire an ajax POST request, rather than a standard browser request because the behaviour you're trying to avoid is exactly what a standard request / response cycle does: browser triggers request and displays response as the next page.

Alternatively, you could probably use some kind of iframe, but that'd be just ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return a HTTP response without any content:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse()
```